# Как вставить java-апплет на HTML-страницу?

Tags: веб-программирование, web-apps, java, html

Я на страницу своего [сайта](http://delphiprog.my1.ru) попробовал вставить простейший java код. Вот, что у меня [получилось](http://delphiprog.my1.ru/index/ehksperement_2/0-10)! 
Там пусто!
Я пробовал сделать это с помощью тега <applet>
Вот это код:

```
<applet code="
class OneMoreHello {
public static void main(String[] args) {
byte age=12;
char sex='м';
double weight=41.2;
int height=145;
System.out.println("Персональные данные пользователя:");
System.out.println("Возраст: "+age+" лет");
System.out.println("Пол(м/ж): "+sex+".");
System.out.println("Вес: "+weight+" кг");
System.out.println("Рост: "+height+" см");
}
}
" >
```

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Вы сначала научитесь отличать JavaScript от Java

Answer (score 5):

Вот [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp) написано, что атрибут:

> code: URL - Specifies the file name of a Java applet
>
> codebase: URL- Specifies a relative base URL for applets specified in the code attribute

Т.е. для работы в качестве апплета, вам необходимо создать сам апплет, откомпилировать его в Java, получив файл `your_app.class` и к нему указать путь в `code`.